# Double loop with dictionary avoiding repetitions

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Consider the following code snippet:

```
foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

for k1 in foo:
    for k2 in foo:
        print(foo[k1], foo[k2])
```

The output will be

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1 
1 2
2 0
2 1 
2 2
```

I do not care for the order of the key couples, so I would like a code that outputs

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1 
1 2
2 2
```

I tried with

```
foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

foo_2 = foo.copy()

for k1 in foo_2:
    for k2 in foo_2:
        print(foo[k1], foo[k2])
    foo_2.pop(k1)
```

but I clearly got

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Other solutions?

Comment: In your example the values are unique (0, 1, 2). Can we assume they are unique? or they can be repeated?

Comment: You can assume they are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

foo_2 = foo.copy()

for k1 in foo:
    for k2 in foo_2:
        print(foo[k1], foo[k2])
    foo_2.pop(k1)
```

You looped in `foo_2` two times and when you tried to pop `k1` from `foo_2` it changed the dictionary while looping causing the error so by first looping `foo` you avoid the error.

Comment: Might be the nicest answer (since you didn't ignore the OP's attempt) if you at least pointed out what you changed (and perhaps why).

Comment: Btw it doesn't only avoid that error. If it *were* allowed, it would likely mess up the outer iteration, making it "skip" every second value (like when you do the same thing with a list).

Comment: Thanks that's the best for me, as I need to access ```k1``` and ```k2``` in the loop for other operations (the key, not the value). All approaches below are based on loops on the values, which would make not nice to go back to the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> keys = list(foo.keys())
>>> for i, v in enumerate(keys):
...     for j, v2 in enumerate(keys[i:]):
...             print(foo[v], foo[v2])
... 
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach.

```
foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

for v1 in foo.values():
    for v2 in foo.values():
        if v1 <= v2:
            print(v1, v2)
```

It could be done with [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) as well:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

print(*[f'{foo[k1]} {foo[k2]}' for k1, k2 in combinations_with_replacement(foo.keys(), r=2)], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the values of **foo** dictionary to a list and loop.

```
foo = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
val_list = list(foo.values())

for k1 in foo.values():
  for row in val_list:
    print(k1, row)
  val_list.pop(0)
```